# Issue with Jekyll on GitHub

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm having a problem with loading work section, on my web site. This is the repo: https://github.com/Vukasin90/test/blob/gh-pages/_includes/work.html

and this is the we site: https://vukasin90.github.io/test/

when you click thumbnails, it should open a bounch of images and paragraphs, basically a html document.

When I run it locally, it works just fine, but on gh-pages it wont load (there's only a spinner animation, which I've put to show when loading is slow).

I'm guessing that it can't be done this way on GitHub, but I don't have any idea how to go around this problem. Or maybe I made mistake with links, or something. I really don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an issue with your js, not Jekyll.

Jquery is requesting: `https://vukasin90.github.io/work/work-1.html`

Instead of `https://vukasin90.github.io/`**test**`/work/work-1.html`

There are other js errors too - other 404s and blocked resources.

If you want to reference full paths in jekyll, you should use site.url and site.baseurl with something like:

`..data-folder="{{ site.url|append: site.baseurl }}/work/work-1" style="background-image: url({{ site.url|append: site.baseurl }}/Assets/img/work/proj-1/thumb.jpg"..)`

Have fun.

**EDIT:**

Amended above to show on page changes better.

Alternately, if you want to fix keeping your inline relative references, then change these:

`...data-folder="../work/work-1"...`

To:

`...data-folder="../test/work/work-1"...`

However, keep in mind this path reference issue between Jekyll and your js could crop up in other ways. So id recommend using full path references throughout or change your js setup to include the baseurl.

Comment: Could you make a pull request? I'm not that experienced with JS, yet, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. 
I tried couple of things, but nothing seems to work. I used full path, I changed JS (I added /test/work/...), a tried data-folder="../test/work/work-1" 
I left it changed. JS is changed, I added /test/ and work section is back how it was... 

It's driving me crazy :D

Comment: I found the solution!
Thank you very much, for point out where the problem is!! :)

I add in JS /test/work...
And in data-folder just typed the name of html doc. for example "work-1"